# System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException exception occur in fiddler on running Web API post request in fiddler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am new in ASP.NET MVC web api. I am trying to run default web api project created by visual studio 2013. Also, I am using fiddler to test web api.

In that default project a post method is created 'api/Account/Register'. When I try to run this in fiddler UnsupportedMediaTypeException occurs. I search a lot and tried adding content type content-type: application/json; header in fiddler's composer section. But exception still occurs. Following is the complete exception detail -

{"Message":"The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'RegisterBindingModel' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Here is my setting in fiddler - 
[image]

[image]

please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to insert an accept header:

```
Accept: */*
```

Meaning: Give what you have...

Or

```
Accept: application/json
```

Meaning: Give me JSON

Comment: tried adding accept header ... no change , issue still occurs

Comment: Actually it seems to be something wrong with you Content-Type header.

Comment: Try replace the case ("Content-Type: application/json") and remove de semicolon at the end...

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)

Comment: Fiddler is excellent.  But I personally do all of my API testing using https://www.getpostman.com/